# NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element (aka Any) does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3, xcode8

After upgrading to Xcode 8 (Swift 3), my Firebase queries have the error `NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element (aka Any) does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'` when I try to step through child records in a snapshot:

```
for child in snapshot.children {
                if (child as AnyObject).value!["postedBy"] != nil {
```

Xcode changed `child.value["postedBy"]` to `(child as AnyObject).value!["postedBy"]` which throws the error. I then tried changing it to

```
((child as AnyObject).value as? NSDictionary)["postedBy"] != nil
```

but then it throws a different error `Binary operator != cannot be applied to operands of type _ and _`

Am I going in the right direction? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

**Final solution:**

```
for child in snapshot.children{
                if let postedBy = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["postedBy"] as? String {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :-

```
  for child in snapshot.children{
            if let postedBy = child.value!["postedBy"] as? String { .. }}
```

Comment: Error appears on first line: `Cannot convert value of type 'NSEnumerator' to type 'NSDictionary` in coercion

Comment: I think so! I had to change it to `if let postedBy = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["postedBy"] as? String {` Thank you!!